# C# Accepting sockets in async fasion - best practices

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous

What is the best way to accept new sockets in async way.

**First way:**

```
while (!abort && listener.Server.IsBound)
{  
  acceptedSocketEvent.Reset();  
  listener.BeginAcceptSocket(AcceptConnection, null);  

  bool signaled = false;  
  do  
  {  
     signaled = acceptedSocketEvent.WaitOne(1000, false);
  } while (!signaled && !abort && listener.Server.IsBound);
}
```

where *AcceptConnection* should be:

```
private void AcceptConnection(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    // Signal the main thread to continue.
    acceptedSocketEvent.Set();

    Socket socket = listener.EndAcceptSocket(ar);
    // continue to receive data and so on...
    ....
}
```

**or Second way:**

```
listener.BeginAcceptSocket(AcceptConnection, null);
while (!abort && listener.Server.IsBound)
{  
   Thread.Sleep(500);
}
```

and *AcceptConnection* will be:

```
private void AcceptConnection(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    Socket socket = listener.EndAcceptSocket(ar);
    // begin accepting next socket
    listener.BeginAcceptSocket(AcceptConnection, null);
    // continue to receive data and so on...
    ....
}
```

What is your prefered way and why?

Comment: My preferred way is to use F#, where this is all simple and sane: http://lorgonblog.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!701679AD17B6D310!1847.entry

Comment: A way that doesn't involve learning a whole other language would probably be more helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really like the second way; continuing to "BeginAccept" from the event that accepts the connection seems more readable to me. You can even attach the Listening socket to the IAsyncResult, and fetch it in your Accept event, to avoid the use of any globals.

Comment: Thinking about second way too, but this has possibility to not call BeginAccept when some exception occurs within AcceptSocket method and this listener never accept any new connections.

Comment: The exception will be raised by calling EndAcceptSocket, which you can then catch and finally start the BeginAccept again.